# Python nan and None

Tags: python, pandas, scd2

I am trying to apply the SCD2 with Python.
The source files are .xlsx files and will be loaded into PostgreSQL.

I have applied the condition where I identify the changed rows in the merged dataframe by:

```
ChangedRecords = np.where((All_Data.is_current_x.notnull()) & (All_Data.is_current_y.notnull())
                              & ((All_Data['col1_x'] != All_Data['col1_y'])
                                 | (All_Data['col2_x'] != All_Data['col2_y'])
                                 | (All_Data['col3_x'] != All_Data['col3_y'])
                                 ... ),1,0)
```

The issue I am having is that the NULL values in source (.xlsx) are displayed as `nan`
and the NULL values in destination (PostgreSQL) are displayed as `None` and therefore my code is considering these values as different and whenever a row has NULL value it gets in ChangedRecords which is wrong.

The datatype of the column is String.

I have used the below code to replace, but it seems like is not working.

```
Source = ftp_invoices.replace([np.nan],[None])
```

I still get `nan` in NULL values

Comment: Try df.filna().

Comment: Ssying *"NULL values in source (.xlsx) are displayed as nan and the NULL values in destination"* is totally unclear, it doesn't tell us whether you mean in Excel, Python or SQL respectively, or their datatype (string, numeric or what?). Python and SQL represent datatypes differently. Please edit your question to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If think `nan` is a string and not `NaN` (see the case).

Try:

```
Source = ftp_invoices.replace('nan', None)
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [None, np.NaN, 'nan']})
print(df)

# Output
      A
0  None  # <- None
1   NaN  # <- np.NaN
2   nan  # <- the string nan
```

```
# Replace real NaN by None
>>> df.replace(np.NaN, None)
      A
0  None
1  None  # Only here
2   nan

# Replace nan strings by None
>>> df.replace('nan', None)
      A
0  None
1   NaN
2  None  # Only here

# Combine all
>>> df.replace({'nan': None, np.NaN: None})
      A
0  None
1  None
2  None
```